# Difference between "vorher" and "vorhin"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Can *vorher* be replaced with *vorhin*?

> Wir machen nicht, wie vorhin angesagt...

Can we replace here *vorher*? What is the difference between the two words?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Vorher" (and, equivalently, "davor") means "before" or "earlier", so it's relative to *some point in time* that should be clear from the context. 
"Vorhin" means "a short time ago", so it's relative to *now*.